# LibGDX - Reading "uiskin.json" in HTML mode

Tags: json, gwt, libgdx, scene2d

When I RUN my game project in HTML mode, it runs.
But when i DEPLOY it, after I upload it to a server, that error happens:

```
GwtApplication: exception: Error reading file: uiskin.json
Error reading file: uiskin.json
Error reading file: uiskin.json
Error parsing file: uiskin.json
usikin.json does not exist
```

Skin file which is used for widgets cannot be read.

Why is it running only on localhost?

Comment: check [this thread](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=9083), maybe could be useful

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I fixed it after 2 days of searching by replacing uisking.json file *(It seems the native uiskin.json file has syntax errors when reading it in html)*

**So, try to use this uisking.json:**
https://gist.github.com/St1nger13/560d5deaec7c3a4d15d477f43a1095b7

Let me know please, if it helped you :)